# HDF error with rotate() function raster package ncdf file

Tags: r, gdal, netcdf, r-raster

[1]I want to rotate a `netcdf` file with Lon 0, 360 to -180, 180. Easy enough, but when I try to use the `rotate()` function in Rstudio I get the following error:

```
Error in Rsx_nc4_get_vara_double: NetCDF: HDF error
Var: pr  Ndims: 3   Start: 558,0,0 Count: 1,144,96
Fehler in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  : 
  C function R_nc4_get_vara_double returned error
```

I have the raster, regal and ncdf4 package installed. I have tried to installed the rgdal package but it tells me that that is not available to my version of R.
I previously worked on Mac, but having a bunch of problems with the rgdal package (and this HDF error) I switched to Windows 10 with high hopes of that being the solution to my problem, but unfortunately it was not. So I got the exact same error on Mac and Windows, a friend tried the code and files on his Windows machine and it worked like it should. I am new to R and programming and don't know what to try. Help is much appreciated!

That is my code:

```
library(raster)   
Stack.nc <- stack("pr_Amon_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_185001-201412.nc")
StackRot.nc <- rotate(Stack.nc)`
```

[Here it the website I got the file from and hopefully all the variables I selected
https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/search/cmip6-dkrz/

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be related to `rgdal`, as your script does not use it (I removed `library(rgdal)` from your example to make that clearer).

I assume this also not just with rotate, but that any attempt to read the data will fail. For example, can you do

```
s <- Stack.nc * 1
```

*update*.

It works for me with the file provided

```
f <- "pr_Amon_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_185001-201412.nc"
```

With `terra`

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(f)
rr <- rotate(r)

rr    
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 144, 192, 1980  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1.875, 1.25  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       :         pr_1,         pr_2,         pr_3,         pr_4,         pr_5,         pr_6, ... 
#min values  : 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, ... 
#max values  : 0.0004399522, 0.0004903608, 0.0003187894, 0.0004326741, 0.0003904318, 0.0006041837, ...
```

And with `raster`

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(f)
bb <- rotate(b)

bb
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 144, 192, 27648, 1980  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1.875, 1.25  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      :  X1850.01.16,  X1850.02.15,  X1850.03.16,  X1850.04.16,  X1850.05.16,  X1850.06.16,  X1850.07.16,  X1850.08.16,  X1850.09.16,  X1850.10.16,  X1850.11.16,  X1850.12.16,  X1851.01.16,  X1851.02.15,  X1851.03.16, ... 
#min values : 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 4.140691e-18, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, ... 
#max values : 0.0004399522, 0.0004903608, 0.0003187894, 0.0004326741, 0.0003904318, 0.0006041837, 0.0008112662, 0.0006924249, 0.0005891759, 0.0003935274, 0.0003543252, 0.0003916493, 0.0004465098, 0.0004070048, 0.0003241026, ... 
Date       : 1850-01-16, 2014-12-16 (min, max)
```

Are you using the current version of R? You say that "rgdal is not available to my version of R", that suggest that you are using a rather old version perhaps? Can you show your `sessionInfo()`? Can you reinstall the relevant packages?
`install.packages(c("raster", "ncdf4", "terra"))`

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! You are right, I get the same error trying 
s<-Stack.nc*1
I tried it with terra, on the Mac it rotated it but to 0,180, so it looked more cropped. On the Windows it terminated Rstudio always when I ran 
y<-rotate(x)

I also downloaded the file again but it made no difference.

I tried to put the link here to the file, but I am not sure it works.

Comment: It would need to be the file that you are using. You can share it with google drive or such.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cnnnRS_IJedX6j5TFMVAMRcGHMXusAZg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello Robert, with "rgdal is not available to my version of R" I meant due to the Update to BigSur, it was difficult to install it on Mac. On Windows it worked fine, I have the newest R version. I tried to rotate a NetCDF from a different model (the file I used in the problem was from ACCESS-CM2), and it worked.